# Modula Mathematics and Triple

Tags: haskell

I have kind of an interesting problem which I have been unable to solve for the past few days.

In Haskell, I have method:

```
c :: Int->(Int,Int,Int)
c x = ...
```

Considering the three elements of the returned value to be a,b,c such that the returned value is (a,b,c) then the function should take the input value, and proceed as follows:

Increase the value of a by 1, and at the same time decrease x by 1.

If at any time a is equal to 25, then at the next step a is set to 0 and b is increased by 1, x is decreased by 1.

If at any time b is equal to 25, then at the next step b is set to 0 (consequently also a is set to 0) and c is increased by 1, x is decreased by 1.

If at any time a,b and c are equal to 25, then they are all reset to 0 and at the next step the returned value would be (1,0,0), x is decreased by 1.

For example, for x = 20 the returned value would be (20,0,0), for x = 29 the returned value would be (3,1,0)

Any idea on how to best implement this?

Comment: Are we to assume that `a`, `b`, and `c` start out at 0?  Also, is there any reason to implement the algorithm as written, or would you also accept a simple expression using `quot` and `rem`?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Forgot to mention that!

Comment: Are you sure the value for `29` is `(3, 1, 0)` and not `(4, 1, 0)`?

Comment: At step 25 it becomes (25,0,0), step 26 is (0,1,0), 27 (1,1,0), 28 (2,1,0), 29 (3,1,0)

Comment: For the second, third, and fourth rules, it doesn't say that `x` is then decreased though, right? So on the 26th step wouldn't it go `(25, 0, 0) -> (0, 1, 0) -> (1, 1, 0)`? Edit: Actually, it isn't specified which order the rules are applied? So maybe on step 25 it would go `(24, 0, 0) -> (25, 0, 0) -> (0, 1, 0)`?

Comment: Apologies, yes, x is always decreased, I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems here I'm not sure you're aware of:

- > In Haskell, I have method

  No, you don't! `c` is simply a function. (What we call "methods" in Haskell are functions as well, but those declared in a type class.) Functions are something quite different from methods in OO languages, which you may have in mind. In particular...
- It's not possible to "set" any values. In Haskell, all variables are defined once and for as long as anyone uses them. You can't just change them. You may talk about "replacing" which can make sense for "update-functions" of the form `(a,b,c) -> (a,b,c)`. But that can't apply to you example.

  `x` is a parameter, so the function doesn't have any say in what value it might take at all. What you mean by "decrease `x` by 1" really tries to descibe a *correlation* between `x` and `a`. A more correct way to do that would be "if `x` *increases* by one, then `a` also increases by 1".

You probably do know this, but haven't really ingested the way of thinking functionally yet. It's generally not great to describe what a function is supposed to yield by such a sequence of steps.

Your requirements could be formulated much more precise and simple, but it requires some nomenclature. First strip away everything unnecessary.

You have two basically irrelevant numbers in here: a **3**-tuple, and the max of **25**. Obviously, nothing would change in principle if you go to a 34-tuple and the max of each entry 35248. So we should instead consider a function

```
c' :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

with the following requirements:

- `c' max 0 ≡ 0`. And `c' max (x+1) ≡ 1 + c' max x`, provided...
- the result doesn't get larger than `max`. If we reach that limit, then the result should be "folded back" to 0 and from there, with each step up of `x`, increase again.

Now, it turns out (something you just need to know) that every common programming language has such a function built in. It's called `mod`.

> GHCi> 0 `mod` 26
>   0
>   GHCi> 1 `mod` 26
>   1
>   GHCi> 2 `mod` 26
>   2
>   GHCi> 24 `mod` 26
>   24
>   GHCi> 25 `mod` 26
>   25
>   GHCi> 26 `mod` 26
>   0
>   GHCi> 27 `mod` 26
>   1

Then we want to get in those other tuple elements. Think about how `b` is *related* to `x`. Basically, the range from `0` to `x` has "partitions" in which `a` increases. The size of these partitions is `max`. `b` signifies how often you have gone over the limit, or, equivalently, how many partitions you have walked over. So how many partitions fit in the range? Well, it's just division! But a special division, *roundoff integer division*, because a partition you've only walked part of doesn't count. In Haskell, you can use `div` for that (or `quot`):

> GHCi> 1 `div` 26
>   0
>   GHCi> 25 `div` 26
>   0
>   GHCi> 26 `div` 26
>   1
>   GHCi> 36 `div` 26
>   1
>   GHCi> 52 `div` 26
>   2

That's not quite sufficient for `b`, because...

> GHCi> 2352 `div` 26
>   90

But `b` should again be limited to `max`. Well, but you can simply use `mod` again!

For `c`, we can apply the same reasoning but in two steps. The function could then look like:

```
c'' :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int, Int)
c'' max x = (a' `mod` max, b' `mod` max, c' `mod` max)
 where a' = x
       b' = x `div` max
       c' = b' `div` max
```

Obviously, there's a pattern here: *repeat application of `` `div` max ``, and on all the results call `` `mod` max ``*. Therefore, the function could easily work with variable-length tuples (lists!) and do the steps automatically.

Comment: @DarioP: They are just names, Haskell allows apostrophes in identifiers. This is just a coding convention, usually specifying that `x` and `x'` are somehow related.

Answer (score 0):

This works....

```
map ord $ showIntAtBase 26 chr 29 ""
```

(you will need to import Numeric and Data.Char)

If you really want your answer in tuple form, pipe the answer through this

```
convertToTuple [x] = (x, 0, 0)
convertToTuple [y, x] = (x, y, 0)
convertToTuple (z:y:x:_) = (x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply do,

```
c x = ( rem x 26, rem (div x 25) 26, rem (div x (26*26)) 26)
```

It gives

```
c 20 = (20,0,0)
c 29 = (3,1,0)
```

More pedantically,

```
  -- Digit to the base 'n'
  data Digit  = Digit  Int  Int  deriving Show
  data Digits = Digits [Digit]   deriving Show

  instance Eq Digit where 
           (==) (Digit m n) (Digit p q) = and [ m == p, n == q ]


  zero :: Int -> Digit 
  zero n = Digit 0 n

  succD (Digit l n) = Digit m n
        where m' = l + 1
              m  | m' == n   = 0
                 | otherwise = m'


  zeroDS n = Digits [zero n]

  succDS (Digits [])                  = error "Should not happen"
  succDS (Digits (x@(Digit m n):[]))  = let y = succD x
                                            z = zero n
                                        in case y == z of
                                           True       -> Digits $ y:(succD z):[]
                                           otherwise  -> Digits $ y:[] 
  succDS (Digits (x@(Digit m n):xs))  = let y = succD x
                                            z = zero  n
                                        in case y == z of
                                           True       -> Digits $ y : ys
                                           otherwise  -> Digits $ y : xs 
                                           where
                                                    ds (Digits digits) = digits 
                                                    ys = ds (succDS (Digits xs))
```

Running,

```
foldl (\x _ -> succDS x) (zeroDS 26) [1..29]
```

should give

```
Digits [Digit 3 26,Digit 1 26]
```

or more familiar,

```
foldl (\x _ -> succDS x) (zeroDS 10) [1..100]
```

should result in,

```
Digits [Digit 0 10,Digit 0 10,Digit 1 10]
```